# Bootstrap Navbar wont toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

Hello I am having trouble figuring out why my navbar menu doesnt open when the navbar is collapsed. I am using Angular 4 (cli), Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta and sass. I'm also using ngx-bootstrap if that matters

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/view']">View
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"[routerLink]="['/upload']">Upload</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown>
          <a dropdownToggle  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
            Print
          </a>
          <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onPrint(1)">Landscape</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onPrint()">Portrait</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

angular-cli.json

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
  ],
```

styles.scss

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

I've also created a plunkr

http://embed.plnkr.co/2CYpsoQAQEOPljR17Pjq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the JavaScript files on your page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

On their "Getting Started" page it tells you which files to include:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Ahh I see. I was trying to avoid including jquery since I'm using angular. Is there any other way to do it without including it?

Comment: Unfortunately not if you want to use any element of bootstrap that involves JavaScript (which the nav does).  From their docs: "Be sure to place jQuery and Tether first, as our code depends on them".  You could look into using something like this if you wanted to avoid the js in Bootstraps navigation: http://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with including jquery into an angular app. Especially if you're trying to use something that depends on jquery. Just don't use native jquery in your app. If you really dont want to include jquery, why not use material2? its further along in their development than bootstrap4 is